# Is it possible to call a variable in jQuery within a loop referencing the index

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I'm really not sure about how to explain my problem so I have pasted my code below. I basically have three variables that end in a number, and I would like to call each variable inside a loop which references the loop index.

```
textLine1 = "This is line 1";
textLine2 = "This is line 2";
textLine3 = "This is line 3";

function text(i) {
  for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    $('.line__' + i).html(textLine(i) would go here);
  }
}

text();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason you couldn't declare these as an array?

```
var textLines = ["This is Line 1", "This is..."];

function text() {
  for (var i = 0; i < textLines.length; i++) {
    $('.line__' + i + 1).html(textLine[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: That would be better! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Put your variables into an array and then access the appropriate array element:

```
var textLine = ["This is line 1", "This is line 2", "This is line 3"];

function text() {
  for (var i = 0; i < textLine.length; i++) {
    $('.line__' + (i+1)).html(textLine[i]);
  }
}

text();
```

Notes:

1. Arrays are `0` indexed so the first array element is at `textLine[0]` so you need to change your `for` loop to start at `0`.
2. Your local variable `i` should be declared as a local variable with `var` so it is not an accidental global (I'm not sure why you declared it as an argument as it wasn't being used that way).
3. For ease of maintenance, your `for` loop should compare to `textLine.length` rather than a hard-coded constant.

---

A little more compact way to code this would be like this:

```
var textLine = ["This is line 1", "This is line 2", "This is line 3"];

textLine.forEach(function(item, index) {
    $('.line__' + (index+1)).html(item);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, an array is best suited for this purpose.

But for those who have no control over how the variables are declared, you can use the following.

```js
textLine1 = "This is line 1";
textLine2 = "This is line 2";
textLine3 = "This is line 3";

function text(i) {
  for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    $('.line__' + i).html(window['textLine' + i]);
  }
}

text();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="line__1"></div>
<div class="line__2"></div>
<div class="line__3"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var textLines = ["This is Line 1", "This is Line 2","This is Line 3"];

function text() {
  for (var i = 0; i < textLines.length; i++) {
    $('.line__' + (i + 1)).html(textLines[i]);
  }
}

text();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="line__1"></div>
<div class="line__2"></div>
<div class="line__3"></div>
```